# 1 Peter 1: 5- "who by God’s power are being guarded through faith "- How the "being guarded" done?

Tags: soteriology, 1-peter

Would this mode - "**being guarded**"(v5) from the various trials (v6) - be a "**norm**" for believers until the journey ends?

Context: 1 Peter 1:5-6 (ESV)

"who "by God’s power are being guarded through faith" (ἐν δυνάμει Θεοῦ φρουρουμένους διὰ πίστεως) a salvation ready to be revealed in the last time. In this you rejoice, though now for a little while, if necessary, you have been grieved by various trials,"

Comment: @ Dottard, Thanks! It should be "norm."  Spelling corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The text of 1 Peter 1:5 (BLB) is:

> who are being guarded by the power of God through faith, for the
> salvation ready to be revealed in the last time,

Paul expresses this another way, as the "shield of faith" = the divine protection against the attacks of the world which is grasped by faith.  Eph 6:16 which is an allusion to Ps 115:9, 10 and also possibly, 2 Sam 22:3, Prov 30:5, Ps 28:7, etc.

In commenting upon 1 Peter 1:5, MacLaren correctly observes:

> **There is no keeping by God without faith**.
>
> Peter was an expert in such matters, for he had had a bitter
> experience to teach him how soon and surely self-confidence became
> self-despair. ‘Though all should forsake Thee, yet will not I,’ was
> said but a few hours before he denied Jesus. His faith failed, and
> then the divine guard that was keeping his soul passed thence, and,
> left alone, he fell.
>
> That divine Power is exerted for our keeping on condition of our
> trusting ourselves to Him and trusting Him for ourselves. And that
> condition is no arbitrary one, but is prescribed by the very nature of
> divine help and of human faith.

Benson also says:

> 1 Peter 1:5. Who are kept — Who, though now surrounded with many
> apparent dangers, are not left defenceless, but are guarded, kept as
> in a garrison, as the word φρουρουμενους signifies; by the power of
> God — Which worketh all in all; or secured from all real harm, under
> the observation of his all-seeing eye, and the protection of his
> almighty hand; through faith — Through the continued exercise of that
> faith, by which alone salvation is both received and retained. The
> clause is very emphatical: “It represents,” says Macknight, “believers
> as attacked by evil spirits and wicked men, their enemies, but
> defended against those attacks by the power of God, through the
> influence of their faith, (1 John 5:4,) just as those who remain in an
> impregnable fortress are secured from the attacks of their enemies by
> its ramparts and walls.”

Barnes says;

> Who are kept by the power of God - That is, "kept" or preserved in the
> faith and hope of the gospel; who are preserved from apostacy, or so
> kept that you will finally obtain salvation. The word which is used
> here, and rendered "kept," (φρουρέω phroureō,) is rendered in 2
> Corinthians 11:32, kept with a garrison; in Galatians 3:23, and here,
> kept; in Philippians 4:7, shall keep. It does not elsewhere occur in
> the New Testament. It means to keep, as in a garrison or fortress; or
> as with a military watch. The idea is, that there was a faithful
> guardianship exercised over them to save them from danger, as a castle
> or garrison is watched to guard it against the approach of an enemy.
> ...
>
> Through faith - That is, he does not keep us by the mere exertion of
> power, but he excites faith in our hearts, and makes that the means of
> keeping us. As long as we have faith in God, and in his promises, we
> are safe. When that fails, we are weak; and if it should fail
> altogether, we could not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1 Peter 1:5- “who by God’s power are being guarded through faith ”- How the “being guarded” done?

Vine's Expository notes the word "[guard](https://www.studylight.org/dictionaries/ved/g/guard.html)":

> phroureó (φρουρέω, 5432), a military term, “to keep by guarding, to keep under
> guard,” as with a garrison (phrousos, “a guard, or garrison”)

> It is used of the security of the Christian until the end, 1 Pet. 1:5, RV, “are guarded,” and of the sense of that security that is his when he puts all his matters into the hand of God, Phil. 4:7, RV, “shall guard.” In these passages the idea is not merely that of protection, but of inward garrisoning as by the Holy Spirit; in Gal. 3:23 (“were kept in ward”), it means rather a benevolent custody and watchful guardianship in view of worldwide idolatry (cf. Isa. 5:2).

This would bring to mind one of the centurions that guarded, or watched over, Paul during his house arrest.

Thus, 1 Peter 1:5 is talking about how Jehovah God is "watching over us" and ready to answer any prayer we make to him in order to help us do his will.

Comment: When you say the security of the Christian until the end is "of inward garrisoning as by the Holy Spirit", would that mean that all such 'guarded' believers must have the indwelling of the Holy Spirit, so that it is the Holy Spirit who does the guarding?

Comment: @Anne I would like to clarify that those are not my words but I did quote Vine's Expository and agree with it. The context of 1 Peter 1:5 shows that Peter was addressing those whom Jehovah God had chosen (see vs. 3).

Comment: Yes, indeed, and the Holy Spirit is the agency of that guarding, yes? So when Romans 8 speaks of Christians having the inward witness of the Holy Spirit, assuring them of being with Christ, that gives them such assurance of security.